Why is INSERT INTO EXEC slower than INSERT INTO SQL?
I have a stored procedure that returns around 8M rows. The goal is to insert into a table the output of the stored procedure.
If I do the following, it takes 10 minutes:
INSERT INTO TBLNAMEHERE
    EXEC SPNAMEHERE

Whereas within the stored procedure if I place the INSERT INTO, then it runs in 2 minutes.
What's the cause of this large time difference?

They don't seem to be a completely equavalent operation, read https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5849/sql-server-query-performance-for-insert-select-vs-insert-exec/ for example. I would avoid INSERT/EXEC if possible, it's very brittle and sign of bad code/planning

If you write
insert into #temp
Exec dbo.your_sp

This plan will load data to parameter table first before loading it to your actual table you intended to. 
This will impact time it takes to load data. This will be especially evident when you load a lot of data like 8M.
Much better would be to load data directly
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
SELECT columns...
FROM dbo.YourSourceTable

If you worried about speed you might want to consider adding WITH (TABLOCK). This will make insert faster, but it will put a lock for the whole table.
